# Flask streaming doesn't work on my machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, server-sent-events

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233191/why-does-my-generator-block-flask-from-sending-sse-responses).

I'm trying to use Flask streaming and having difficulty doing so, it seems my example works on any machine I try it on other than my own. I'm running Flask 0.10.1, Werkzeug 0.9.4, and Python 2.7.6. I have reinstalled Flask and Werkzeug with no effect. If someone could suggest a way to debug this I would be very grateful.

The problem I experience is that data doesnt get sent to the client while the stream is open, it is only sent once the stream is closed (eg in the example below when the generator function returns).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, Response
from time import sleep

def stream():
    n = 10
    while n > 0:
        yield "data: hi\n\n"
        sleep(0.5)
        n = n - 1

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/events")
def streamSessionEvents():
    return Response(
        stream(),
        mimetype="text/event-stream"
    )

#...also has a route to output html/js client to consume the above

app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: Did you check with `curl` or similar if the server is at fault here or your browser?

Comment: If I run "curl -N http://127.0.0.1:5000/events" on the machine that I'm having difficulty with it waits 5 secs and then outputs all of the events in one go.

Comment: That narrows it down a little, at least. Can you confirm with `import flask; print flask.__version__` and `import werkzeug; print werkzeug.__version__` print the correct versions? What OS is this?

Comment: That said, I just ran the same command on a different machine (Flask still running on the first machine) and I get the correct behaviour.  If I run the same test with the machines switched I also get the correct behaviour.

Comment: So something is filtering or proxying your localhost connections. A firewall perhaps?

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.9, my firewall is disabled, I have some irritating antivirus crap that work mandates. I just attempted to kill it and I'm still getting the same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisited this recently, it was indeed the virus scanner messing with my network traffic.

I'm using Sophos, and found that if I add the address of the machine hosting my Flask application to the virus scanner's "allowed sites" list then my SSE events are received correctly.