# Flask not streaming JSON response

Tags: python, flask, streaming, google-developers-console, buffering

I have below flask application that should stream JSON response

Directory structure:

```
server - 
        api.py
        resources -
                   stream.py
```

api.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.stream import Stream
from flask_compress import Compress

compress = Compress()
app = Flask(__name__)
compress.init_app(app)
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Stream, '/stream')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0')
```

stream.py in resources directory

```
from flask import Response, request, stream_with_context
from flask_restful import Resource

class Stream(Resource):
    def get(self):
        def generator():
            yield '{"data": ['
            #creating large number of entries for data array with yield
            yield ']}'
        resp = Response(stream_with_context(generator()), status=200, content_type='application/json')
        return resp
```

I started the flask app with python3.9 api.py

I am able to get response when I hit url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/stream` but in network tab I can see some issues:

1. If the response was streamed it should not have content-length
2. The streamed response should not be in `Waiting for server response` state, somehow its waiting to finish whole response and then starts downloading.

[image: Content Length]
[image: Output I am getting]

And below is the output that I am trying to achieve. A streamed output which would start `Content Downloading` and not be stuck in `Waiting for server response`
[image: Expected]

Comment: maybe it needs some special header to inform that you stearm data.

Comment: Tried your code with flask 1.1.2 and werkzeug 1.0.1 (my current stack) worked as expected. Maybe the problem is elsewhere, did you have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648948/2307934

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding `Content-Length`, that helped me fix my issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem I faced. I was using flask_compress which was causing this issue. Removing it would stream the response as expected. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had some code in my `after_request` function that called `response.data`, essentially:

```
def after_request(response):
    logging.info(response.data)
```

Apparently, doing this will convert the stream back into a normal response, for example setting Content-Length and removing the Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

I changed this to the following which removed this issue.

```
def after_request(response):
    if response.is_streamed:
        logging.info('<STREAMED>')
    else:
        logging.info(response.data)
```